# Why is scipy.stats.gamma.pdf returning an array of 0s?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, gamma, scipy.stats

I am trying to plot a load of data and identify how it is distributed, I have easily plotted a normal distribution and Beta distribution against my histogram.

[Histogram and density plot. With normal and beta distributions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6vWX.png)

However, when I try and do the same with gamma distribution it just returns an array of mostly zeros. My code is shown below.

```
plt.figure()
sns.distplot(data,bins=50)
x = np.linspace(min(data),max(data),1000)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
plt.plot(x,p)
ag,bg,cg = stats.gamma.fit(data,1)  
pdf_gamma = stats.gamma.pdf(x,ag,bg,cg)  
plt.plot(x, pdf_gamma, label="Gamma")
ab,bb,cb,db = stats.beta.fit(data)  
pdf_beta = stats.beta.pdf(x, ab, bb,cb, db)  
plt.plot(x, pdf_beta, label="Beta")
```

Does anyone know the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 1):

You've called `ag,bg,cg = stats.gamma.fit(data,1)`, which sets the shape parameter **a** to 1. You don't want this. To see what this is doing, try just plotting the estimated gamma PDF with and without setting `a=1`:

```py
x = np.linspace(min(data),max(data),1000)
ag,bg,cg = stats.gamma.fit(data, 1)
pdf_gamma = stats.gamma.pdf(x,ag,bg,cg)
plt.plot(x, pdf_gamma, label="Gamma (a = 1)")

ag,bg,cg = stats.gamma.fit(data)
pdf_gamma = stats.gamma.pdf(x,ag,bg,cg)
plt.plot(x, pdf_gamma, label="Gamma (a = Free)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Removing the 1 from the gamma fit does not make any change to the array that is returned.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about that?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have tried with and without using 1 and the array is still full of zeroes.

Comment: I am having something similar with gamma... Hope to report back with some findings.

Comment: @Eoin I have found out that scipy's gamma _sometimes_ fails with big numbers. Haven't figured out why. You can try yourself by generating some gamma distributed hypothetical data with scipy.stats.gamma.rvs method and then fitting and plotting. Have you figured something else?